# Why is ifelse generating print output?

Tags: r, if-statement

I have some code in my RMarkdown file that I knit:

```
ifelse(Sys.info()[1]=="Linux",
       wdir <- "/path/1",
       wdir <- "/path/2")
setwd(wdir)
```

Except it's supposed to be silent. I've got it in a block with

````
```{r prepare.data,echo=F,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,error=FALSE}
````

I don't want to generate any output from that, yet when I knit, I get this in the output:

```
##                                          sysname 
## "/path/1"
```

I've tried just that code snip in the console and it is generating that print output.

My Questions are:
1. Why is ifelse printing this output?
2. How can I avoid it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  `wdir <- ifelse(Sys.info()[1]=="Linux", "/path/1", "/path/2")`. The reason the output is printed is that if you don't assign the `ifelse` output to some variable, it will just print it on the screen. It is like writing `a <- 1 + 2` vs `1 + 2`.

Comment: I meant to add, perhaps you got confused with the `if..else..` structure which would not generate an output (as it is not a function like `ifelse()`). So `if(Sys.info()[1] == "Linux") wdir <- "path/1" else wdir <- "path/2"` would work too